# Defining "addition" on the Riemann surface of log(z)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

The title of this question is a bit awkward, as adding two points together on a manifold is usually not considered possible, but in this case there appears to be a nice little hack.

Consider the Riemann surface defined by the complex log function. One can (loosely) think of this as the set of complex numbers with "unwrapped" phases, meaning points of the form $R \angle \theta$, except where $\theta$ is now allowed to take any value in $\Bbb R$.

Much like with ordinary complex numbers, we can multiply together two points on this surface by multiplying their radii and adding together their angles. Unfortunately, this does not seem to extend to addition in any ordinary way.

I thought of an interesting little hack that might perhaps help us define addition in a sensible way. Given any two points on this surface, we can first obtain the average of the two, and then double the amplitude of the result while keeping the angle the same. We can find this average by using the Riemannian metric to find the point on the surface which is equidistant to both of the points in question, and which minimizes this distance.

I think this definition might fail for certain pairs of points which are, intuitively, "opposite" one another on the Riemann surface, where the average would (intuitively) be zero, except there is no zero here. However, leaving that undefined for the moment, it seems as though this would yield a useful notion of addition for almost all points on the surface.

Is there any simple expression for this in terms of the polar coordinates of the two points?

Comment: more recently posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291622/defining-addition-on-the-riemann-surface-of-logz